# Allowing Service To Authenticate As User

Tags: windows, permissions, service, runas, impersonation

On Windows XP through 7, I have a service that needs to be able to launch sub-processes as other users. Executing runas would do the trick, but SYSTEM is not configured to use runas without a password for the accounts. Can SYSTEM be configured to be able to authenticate as users without needing a password?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Services control panel
2. Right-click the service in question and go to "Properties"
3. To to the tab "Log On" and check "This Account"
4. Enter the account details of the user you want it to run as (one that can use the RUNAS command without requiring passwords)
5. Click OK and bob's your uncle.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. It needs to be able to launch processes as multiple users. I essentially need to figure out how to delegate runas permissions, the Windows version of visudo.